# firebase friendly chat chat bubbles left and right

Tags: android, listview, firebase

I made the FriendlyChat using firebase

However all the texts are appearing in same line, both from sender and receiver!

I want to apply chat bubbles with left and right alignment but have no idea where to start

I also want to wrap the text view inside chat bubble images? but i have no idea how to do that?

any help!

```
public class MessageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FriendlyMessage> {
public MessageAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<FriendlyMessage> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_message, parent, false);
    }

    ImageView photoImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photoImageView);
    TextView messageTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
    TextView authorTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);

    FriendlyMessage message = getItem(position);

    boolean isPhoto = message.getPhotoUrl() != null;
    if (isPhoto) {
        messageTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        photoImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Glide.with(photoImageView.getContext())
                .load(message.getPhotoUrl())
                .into(photoImageView);
    } else {
        messageTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        photoImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        messageTextView.setText(message.getText());
    }
    authorTextView.setText(message.getName());

    return convertView;
}
```

}

**item_message.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/lp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photoImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messageTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@drawable/messenger_bubble_large_white"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        tools:text="Message" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        tools:text="Name" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post the code what you achieved so far..

Comment: You can use library like chat-ui, Chat messageview https://github.com/bassaer/ChatMessageView

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Parjanya you have have to check type and based upon condition yo can hide one and show other

Comment: So how can i set condition? like sentbyme on right and all others on left?

Comment: add one more param in message object like fromId , set sender userId  and while checking if fromId and current user id is same then it is sent message else it is received.In row item add both send and receive based upon above condition hide and show required one.

Answer (score 0):

for me I used 2 different viewHolder and 2 different xml. My code is below;

MessageChatAdapter.java;

```
public class MessageChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {  
private List<ChatMessage> mChatList;
public static final int SENDER = 0;
public static final int RECIPIENT = 1;

public MessageChatAdapter(List<ChatMessage> listOfFireChats) {
    mChatList = listOfFireChats;     
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (mChatList.get(position).getRecipientOrSenderStatus() == SENDER) {
        return SENDER;
    } else {
        return RECIPIENT;
    }
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());

    switch (viewType) {
        case SENDER:
            View viewSender = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_sender_message, viewGroup, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolderSender(viewSender);
            break;
        case RECIPIENT:
            View viewRecipient = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_recipient_message, viewGroup, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolderRecipient(viewRecipient);
            break;
        default:
            View viewSenderDefault = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_sender_message, viewGroup, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolderSender(viewSenderDefault);
            break;
    }
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    switch (viewHolder.getItemViewType()) {
        case SENDER:
            ViewHolderSender viewHolderSender = (ViewHolderSender) viewHolder;
            configureSenderView(viewHolderSender, position);
            break;
        case RECIPIENT:
            ViewHolderRecipient viewHolderRecipient = (ViewHolderRecipient) viewHolder;
            configureRecipientView(viewHolderRecipient, position);
            break;
    }


}

private void configureSenderView(ViewHolderSender viewHolderSender, int position) {
    ChatMessage senderFireMessage = mChatList.get(position);
    viewHolderSender.getSenderMessageTextView().setText(senderFireMessage.getMessage());
    viewHolderSender.getmTimeStamp().setText(converteTimestamp(senderFireMessage.getTimestap()));

}

private void configureRecipientView(ViewHolderRecipient viewHolderRecipient, int position) {
    ChatMessage recipientFireMessage = mChatList.get(position);
    viewHolderRecipient.getRecipientMessageTextView().setText(recipientFireMessage.getMessage());
    viewHolderRecipient.getmTimeStamp().setText(converteTimestamp(recipientFireMessage.getTimestap()));
}

/*==============ViewHolder===========*/

/*ViewHolder for Sender*/

public class ViewHolderSender extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

    private TextView mSenderMessageTextView;
    private TextView mTimeStamp;

    public ViewHolderSender(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mSenderMessageTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_sender_message);
        mTimeStamp = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);         
    }

    public TextView getSenderMessageTextView() {
        return mSenderMessageTextView;
    }

    public TextView getmTimeStamp() {
        return mTimeStamp;
    }
}


/*ViewHolder for Recipient*/
public class ViewHolderRecipient extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView mRecipientMessageTextView;
    private TextView mTimeStamp;

    public ViewHolderRecipient(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mRecipientMessageTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_recipient_message);
        mTimeStamp = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);      
    }

    public TextView getRecipientMessageTextView() {
        return mRecipientMessageTextView;
    }

    public TextView getmTimeStamp() {
        return mTimeStamp;
    }
}
```

layout_sender_message.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_sender_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="I am doing ok"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="@drawable/sender_rounded_corners"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/text_view_sender_message"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/text_view_sender_message"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

layout_recipient_message.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_recipient_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="Hi. How are you?"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:textColor="#727272"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:background="@drawable/recipient_rounded_corners"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="69dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_view_recipient_message"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:textStyle="italic"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Pretty basic and needs to be fixed but this will give you a headstart.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use two different custom components for chat left and right bubbles.

Set as a background of TextView and make the boolean condition for show and hide two chat bubbles.

If you want more information and demo with use of firebase then please check below link:

https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/firebase/real-time-android-chat-application-using-firebase-tutorial/

I hope it helps you.

Thank you:)

Answer (score -1):

Just two words Answer...

**Use Gravity**

**eg**

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)  _chat_view.getLayoutParams();
lp.gravity = Gravity.END | Gravity.RIGHT;
_chat_view.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

where `_chat_view` is your Message (LinearLayout) container.

Comment: `'messageTextView.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.START);`' not working

Comment: @ParjanyaTW see the edits... set gravity according to message source.. like `msg.isFromMe` then gravity right otherwise `gravity.start`.

Comment: am confused! can u help show the code with my code above? coz what is _chat_view

Comment: its a linear layout(if you have not there, then make one) in your `item_message.xml` and put your `imageView`, `messagetextview` and `name view in that linearlayout. assign an id eg:-  _chat_view.